# Copying class instances

Tags: python, class

All right, so say I have a class. I make an instance of that class and then I want to make a copy of that instance. Like, say I had the instructions for making a car. Then I made a few different cars and all of a sudden I thought that car #7 was the best and I wanted to make another like that. But I'd rather just copy the car, not make a new car with help of the instructions... if that makes sense?

So, simply put, is there any way to make an instance based on another instance?

Comment: That makes perfect sense!

Comment: Just for the comment, this is a well known pattern named "Prototype" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

```
import copy

new_obj = copy.deepcopy(obj)
```

Example:

```
>>> import copy

>>> class A(object):
...     pass
>>> 
>>> obj = A()
>>> new_obj = copy.deepcopy(obj)
>>> 
>>> obj
<__main__.A object at 0xb708216c>
>>> 
>>> new_obj
<__main__.A object at 0xb692b14c>
>>> 
>>> obj is new_obj
False
```